# How can I fix a force only being applied vertically and not horizontally?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am making something where the player is shot in opposite direction that they are looking. Like knockback from their weapon. This code works fine to launch up and down but when I try to make it launch the player horizontally, it just teleports to the side a little bit. When I was researching this, the only thing I saw with a similar problem was because of the animator, but I don't have an animator attached to the player.

```
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody PlayerBody;

[SerializeField] private float Lauchforce;
   
  void Update()
{
    //Walking
    Vector3 MoveVector = transform.TransformDirection(PlayerMovementInput) * Speed;

    PlayerBody.velocity = new Vector3(MoveVector.x, PlayerBody.velocity.y, MoveVector.z);


    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 camDirection = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        Vector3 LaunchVector = transform.TransformDirection(Camera.main.transform.forward);

        PlayerBody.velocity = new Vector3(-LaunchVector.x, -LaunchVector.y, -LaunchVector.z); //just to change direction easily
        PlayerBody.AddForce(-camDirection * Lauchforce, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    MovePlayerCamera();
}
```

Comment: Weird. I’d say I saw the exact type of question multiple times just yesterday, but I can’t find the previous ones…

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Could you add more code, specifically what method the `if` condition is contained in and what calls it.   Please include the [mcve] for `Start`, `Update` and/or `FixedUpdate`.  This will help us help you.  Thanks!

Comment: I just tested It without the walking code and it was working how I wanted it to. So I guess it was a problem with that. I added the walking code to the post. @MickyD

Comment: By the way it's totally fine to answer your _own_ questions.   Just post it below.  This is because posts on Stack Overflow are here for a long time and someone in the future might get the same issue.  If you post below you can even accept your own answer.  Readers who like your posts will up-vote it.   All of this leads to reputation bonuses.  Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code for launching the player works fine. It's the code for walking that is stopping the player from being able to move on the x or z axis without using w a s d keys. The walking code changes the velocity on the x and z axis when the keys are pressed. This means that without the keys being pressed, it always wants to change the velocity to zero. That is why it teleports a little bit, the force is being applied, but the velocity changes back to zero on the next frame.